# What is the significance of saying: "Mustafa", after saying the name of the Messenger (peace and blessing of Allah be upon him)?

Tags: arabic

As-salaamu 'alaykum, wa rahmatullahi wa barakatuh.

As the question states, I was wondering what the significance is of saying "Mustafa" after, for example, the name of our Prophet - peace and blessings of Allah be upon him.

Comment: Could you explain, maybe I got you wrong: I mean we usually use or say al-Mustafa المصطفى  instead of the Prophet or the Messenger of Allah (pbuh). I have never heard somebody saying Mohammad Mustafa or al-Mustafa.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have heard it used at least once, in a lecture by Ustadh Ali Ataie, where he said: "Muhammad, Mustafa (p.b.u.h.)".

Comment: That sounds strange but i can't see any harm in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "**Mustafa**" (المصطفى in arabic) means the chosen one, or the chosen for the prophecy. As our prophet Muhammad was the Mustafa from all of the people.

Answer (score 0):

Muslims do not say Almostafa after the name of the prophet Mohammad , they say it **instead of** his name (PBUH) , because it is one of his names .